# Python requests Response 504

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm learning Python, and I'm trying to request access to a website using the command requests. I'm doing the following:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://www.charitystars.com")
```

However I get `<Response [504]>`, which should be an error because the soup command `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)` returns an empty line. I tried with other websites and I get `<Response [200]>`, and the soup works. So I wonder why the command doesn't work on the first website, and what Response 504 actually means.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @jwodder Thank you. Still, I don't get it. what does it mean? is it just temporarily down? Or there is a way to work this thing out?

Comment: `5xx` mostly means that server has some internal problem and you have to way till admins do something with this problem.

Comment: @furas Ok, so it is a problem on their end, not on mine. for example, I read somewhere that certain website require authorization in order to scrape the data. (I'm a beginner, sorry)

Comment: every page is differnt and may need different solution - some checks `user-agent` to correctly display data. You may need `authorization` if you use API - special urls to get pure data as JSON without all HTML.

Answer (score 9):

This page doesn't like scripts/bots and it checks header `user-agent`.

It can also need this information to display correct page - different for desktop, tablet, smartfon.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

r = requests.get("http://www.charitystars.com/", headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
```

---

**BTW:** `requests` as default uses `"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.1"`

You can use portal http://httpbin.org to see your requests.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")

print(r.text)
```

Comment: could you please explain me why it returns a 200 code if I specify the headers? Thank you!

Comment: some servers check this header to recognize your browser and its capabilities - and then they can use different methods to display page. They use it also to recognize scripts/bots and refuse access.

Comment: BTW: try `r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")` and `print(r.text)` and you see that `requests` as default use `"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.1"`

Answer (score 0):

I got error 504 for load balance timeout. The solution was to run the affected function on the background. My cloud provider offeres that, check for your case.

Also, your cloud provider may be denying access to that website. Check if they may have a white list in place.

Hope it helps.